# magento could not show meta title after removed breadcrumbs

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i want to remove breadcrumbs in my product detail,
i use the code below in my local.xml

```html
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

it work well, but has a little bit problem 
the header meta title was lost, the header meta title only is showed default magento header "Magento Commerce", i don't know what is my mistake, if i remove the xml code the header meta title show title of this produ

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the header of the page there, which is 'root'.  Change your XML to;

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="content">
<remove name="breadcrumbs" />
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: i have tried with your code, but it not working,
I'm using magento v 1.9x you can add your code with "rwd" theme --> not working

Comment: could you elaborate - are the breadcrumbs now showing again?  is the meta title back? etc  Just realised a typo in my answer, corrected now.

Comment: here is my local.xml, your code i have been added at line 63
https://app.box.com/s/4n1oixynnloo583x6dojvi1gplnjd5bs
thanks